# Java code that takes user input of Zipcode and turns it into a bar code

Tags: java, object-oriented

This program works 100%. If someone could help me just separate it into two classes that would be really great. I have been working on it for a while and I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen. This is the full program that I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarCodeConverter {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter a zip code: "); 
    int zip = input.nextInt(); 
    input.close(); 
    int checkDigit = checkDigit(zip); 

    String barcode = "|"; 
    barcode = dBarCode(checkDigit) + barcode; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        barcode = dBarCode(checkDigit) + barcode; 
        zip /= 10; 
    } 
    barcode = "|" + barcode; 
    System.out.println(barcode); 


} 
 public static int checkDigit(int zip) { 
    int remaining = zip; 
    int sum = 0; 
    while (remaining > 0) { 
        sum += remaining % 10; 
        remaining /= 10; 
    } 
    return 10 - (sum % 10); 
} 

public static String dBarCode(int digit) {

    if (digit == 1) { 
        return ":::||"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 2) { 
        return "::|:|"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 3) { 
        return "::||:"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 4) { 
        return ":|::|"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 5) { 
        return ":|:|:"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 6) { 
        return ":||::"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 7) { 
        return "|:::|"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 8) { 
        return "|::|:"; 
    } 
    if (digit == 9) { 
        return "|:|::"; 
    } 
    return "||:::"; 

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My two cents:

I did not know about this system, so the methods don't tell me much. `checkDigit` calculates some kind of validation number? Perhaps name it something like `calculateCheckDigit`. Same for `dBarCode`.

Also, you only ever call `checkDigit` on `zip` once, and then keep on calling it on the `checkDigit` variable, although this one never changes? Could it be a bug?

Some other comments:

- Close the scanner as soon as possible; it is also `AutoCloseable`, so you can use `try-with-resources`: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)
- `dBarCode` can be implemented with a switch statement, an array of `String`s or possibly a `Map`.
- I'd extract the zip to barcode functionality of the main method, without the input/output, to a separate function

I think it is fine to leave the functions in one class, and leave them static.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

> If someone could help me just separate it into two classes that would be really great.

OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of OOP is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (among others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")

So as far as I see there is no need to split this into different classes.

Nevertheless there is some improvement possible by thinking of OOP:

#### Barcode representation of a digit is an object

When changing our mind about the *bar code digits* we might see it this way:

The *bar code digits*  are *stamps* you have in a box on your desk and when converting the next digit of a decimal number you grab the according stamp and punch it on the next place in the result.

In Java *a box* is an implementer of the `Collection` interface. In your case  it would be good to access its elements by *Index* which leads us to the `List` interface which is a child of the `Collection` interface.

Java has a *helper class* that lets us convert some distinct values into a `List`:

```
List<String> barcodeDigits = 
      Arrays.asList("||:::",":::||","::|:|", /* more here */ "|:|::");
```

With this list you could change your method `dBarCode()` tho this:

```
/* mind the new identifier names! */
public static String convertToBarCodeDigit(int decimalDigit) {
   List<String> barcodeDigits = 
      Arrays.asList("||:::",":::||","::|:|", /* more here */ "|:|::");
   return barcodeDigits.get(decimalDigit);
}
```